# I want to give a 270 degree phase shift to an AC Signal

Tags: c, buffer

Suppose I have an AC signal at 50HZ, and I am sampling at 10KHz, Im running this signal on a TI TMS320F28069 micro-controller. I need to give a 270 degrees phase shifty (delay) to the signal before I perform some calculations. what is the simplest way to do this? I have tried implementation using a circular buffer but the function seems too large. I need something simple and efficient. any ideas will be appreciated. This has to be coded in C.

Comment: Well you have 20 data points per cycle than. A 270 degree phase shift is same as throwing away the first 15 data points I guess. So if your function would expect a pointer to this data array I would increase it by 15 before passing to it.

Comment: 10Khz / 50hz = 200 samples not 20. he might not be able to store such a large array. It might be the reason why he does not want to use a buffer.

Comment: Yes exactly, thats why I am looking for a simpler solution, if it exists.

Comment: @Vuddo Kenchi why don't you compute your function y = f(x + phase) each time you want to send a new sample ? can you give us the formula of your function or is it top secret ?

Comment: Not Top secret, we can think of it as a simple sinusoid, say f(wt) = Acos(wt + ph). by computing the function you mean obtaining the amplitude and phase at every sampling time, then shift the sample by the required phase delay? I suppose I could use Goertzel algorithm to do that, but if you have another idea I will take it.

Comment: This might not be practicable, but maybe you could try differentiating the signal. The derivative of sin(x) is cos(x), and −cos(x) is equal to sin(x+3π/2).